# SSRS 2008R2 End User Guide

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm looking for a business/non-technical user guide for SSRS 2008R2 that we can provide to the end users of the system that would cover the following topics:

- Folder Navigation
- Opening a Report
- Filtering a Report
- Exporting a Report
- Drill-Down (expanding rows/columns)
- Drill-Thru (master -> detail)
- Creating / Managing Subscriptiosn

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can find them all at one place:

But you can use the following links and do some cut/pasting to create that doc:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255239(v=sql.105).aspx - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220427(v=sql.105).aspx#HowTo

You can find a good discussion (in non technical terms) for drill through at:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/cfa141cb-c626-41b7-bb1b-d3ca8108cc1a
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa964132(v=SQL.90).aspx

Subscriptions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156307(v=sql.105).aspx

You can probably enhance it by using Snip tool to create screenshots of some of the steps.